# MySQL Replication - Accidentally Dropped Database on Slave

Tags: mysql, replication

I am using MySQL replication and I executed `DROP DATABASE` against my slave by accident (long story). Can I execute `DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS` against my master to safely drop the schema on my master without causing replication to blow up?

This schema is no longer being written to on the master.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should be fine.

You can `DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS mydata;` on the Master should replicate to the Slave, execute the `IF EXISTS` part on the Slave, do nothing, and be successful without erroring out.

I have done this before.

As an alternative, you could also run this on the Master:

```
SET sql_log_bin = 0;
DROP DATABASE mydata;
SET sql_log_bin = 1;
```

or

```
SET sql_log_bin = 0;
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS mydata;
SET sql_log_bin = 1;
```

I have done this before as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can drop the database (***ON MASTER***) and then skip the error (***ON SLAVE***) with:

```
`STOP SLAVE; SET GLOBAL SQL_SLAVE_SKIP_COUNTER=1;`
```

Then you need  to remove the `replicate-do-db yourschema` in your master `my.cnf`. Restart ***MASTER*** server and run on ***SLAVE*** server:

```
`START SLAVE;`
```

Or you can just `STOP SLAVE;`, remove the `replicate-do-db` (***ON MASTER***), restart the ***MASTER*** server and `START SLAVE` (***ON SLAVE***) again.

Comment: I've read that this is an option, but can you explain why my method would not work above?